# Filter Object in ES6 to form another Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like below, am trying to map only certain keys and their values to form another object of array.

Below is my attempt with a single object

```
const object1 = { app_id:35687,codesmell: 30, baz: 42 };
console.log(Object.entries(object1).map(x => {app_id:x.app_id}));
```

I always get undefined, have been searching through mdn and stackoverflow couldnt find a solution. Please help.

Another attempt i tried, this time with arrays where `result` is an array of objects

```
T_BugDetails: result.data.map(x => Object.entries(x).reduce((a,b) => { a, b},{}))
```

Comment: You are forgetting `return`

Comment: You're not returning anything. You might think you are, but the `{}` are indicating the body of the function, not the object o be returned. You can do this; `() => ({ name: value });` or this; `() => { return {name: value}; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some problems:

- `Object.entries` returns an array of *arrays* (an array of the keys and values of the object). If you `.map` the `entries` of an object, the first argument to `.map` should be *an array of the key and value*, like this:

  ```
  Object.entries(object1).map(([key, val]) => ...
  ```
- To return an object from an arrow function, enclose the object's brackets (`{` and `}`) in parentheses, else it will be interpreted as a plain *function block* with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) inside, rather an object to be implicitly returned:

  ```
  => {app_id:x.app_id}
  ```

to

```
    => ({app_id:x.app_id})
```

- But if you just want an object composed of the `app_id` of the original object, don't iterate over the `entries` of the original object, since you only want one property, not all of its properties - instead, just extract the `app_id` of the original object:

```js
const object1 = { app_id:35687,codesmell: 30, baz: 42 };
const { app_id } = object1;
console.log(
  { app_id }
);
```

You would use `.map` only if you have an *array* of objects you need to transform, for example:

```js
const objects = [
  { app_id:35687,codesmell: 30, baz: 42 },
  { app_id:12345,codesmell: 20, baz: 52 }
];
console.log(
  objects.map(({ app_id }) => ({ app_id }))
);
```